# How do I calculate the difference between two dates in dplyr (in days)? R

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to calculate the difference in days between two dates in R. The two dates are in different column and I just need to create another column named DAY_DIFFERENCE. Here is a simple structure of my table:

```
     date1           date2     days_diff
     2021-09-12    2021-09-13      1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a possible solution;

```
date1 <- as.Date("2021-09-12")

date2 <- as.Date("2021-09-13")

datediff <- date2 - date1
```

If you just want the difference as a number

```
as.numeric(datediff)
```

with dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(date1 = c("2021-09-12","2021-09-13"),
                 date2 = c("2021-09-13","2021-10-14"))

df$date1 <- df$date1 %>%
  as.Date()
df$date2 <- df$date2 %>%
  as.Date()

df$datediff <- as.numeric(df$date2 - df$date1)
```

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway you can share an example using dplyr syntax? Meaning would I put this into a summarize or mutate verb?

Comment: see edit, please vote up if it is usefull

Comment: It would be helpful if I could know what verb I input that my dates into. My dates are already formatted as dates. I am just unsure of what verb to include it in

Comment: Not sure what you mean there. If you allready have 2 date columns than the diffrence is just subtracting them(?)

Comment: @Jaskeil You'd put it into a `mutate()` verb.  Something like `my_data %>% mutate(days_diff = as.integer(difftime(date2, date1, "days")))`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `dplyr`. Try `difftime()`.

```
date1 <- "2021-09-12"

date2 <- "2021-09-13"

days_diff <- as.numeric(difftime(date2, date1))

days_diff
# [1] 1
```

Comment: I think OP wants this calculation integrated into a **`dplyr`** workflow.

Comment: @Greg. I see your comment about using `mutate()`, which makes sense.